# ¿Por qué no funciona :hover después de usar Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Haciendo una calculadora, quiero que cuando el cursor pase por las teclas el `background` se ponga verde, y cuando se clicke en las teclas el fondo se ponga de un verde diferente.
Para el `:hover` he usado `css`, para el click he (probado) a usar `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calc").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#197647");
      });
      
      // añado mouseleave para que vuelva al color original para que no se quede el color #197647 guardado después de hacer click:

      $(".calc").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#4A5759");
      });
    
  });
```

```css
.calc:hover{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculadora">
        <div class="divinput">
            <input type="text" name="" id="">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="calc">%</div>
            <div class="calc">√</div>
            <div class="calc">n²</div>
            <div class="calc">1⁄x</div>
            <div class="calc">CE</div>
            <div class="calc">C</div>
            <div class="calc">DEL</div>
            <div class="calc">÷</div>
            <div class="calc">7</div>
            <div class="calc">8</div>
            <div class="calc">9</div>
            <div class="calc">X</div>
            <div class="calc">4</div>
            <div class="calc">5</div>
            <div class="calc">6</div>
            <div class="calc">-</div>
            <div class="calc">1</div>
            <div class="calc">2</div>
            <div class="calc">3</div>
            <div class="calc">+</div>
            <div class="calc">±</div>
            <div class="calc">0</div>
            <div class="calc">,</div>
            <div class="calc">=</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Lo de `jQuery` funciona bien pero sin embargo el `:hover` de `css` ya no funciona o lo hace impredeciblemente.

He probado a hacer el `hover` también en `jQuery`

```
$(".calc").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      },
```

Pero entonces el click es el que no funciona.

Comment: Hola Javier, la función `hover` de jquery la tienes igual en el código? esta mal cerrada, te falta `);` y te sobra la coma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calc").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#197647");
      });
      
      // añado mouseleave para que vuelva al color original para que no se quede el color #197647 guardado después de hacer click:

      $(".calc").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#4A5759");
      });
      
      $(".calc").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      });
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculadora">
        <div class="divinput">
            <input type="text" name="" id="">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="calc">%</div>
            <div class="calc">√</div>
            <div class="calc">n²</div>
            <div class="calc">1⁄x</div>
            <div class="calc">CE</div>
            <div class="calc">C</div>
            <div class="calc">DEL</div>
            <div class="calc">÷</div>
            <div class="calc">7</div>
            <div class="calc">8</div>
            <div class="calc">9</div>
            <div class="calc">X</div>
            <div class="calc">4</div>
            <div class="calc">5</div>
            <div class="calc">6</div>
            <div class="calc">-</div>
            <div class="calc">1</div>
            <div class="calc">2</div>
            <div class="calc">3</div>
            <div class="calc">+</div>
            <div class="calc">±</div>
            <div class="calc">0</div>
            <div class="calc">,</div>
            <div class="calc">=</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

El problema lo tienes debido a la "Especifidad" del **CSS**. La función `css()` de Jquery es como definir la regla **CSS** en un `style` de **HTML**, por lo que siempre va a tener mayor prioridad que lo que definas a nivel de **CSS**.

La mejor solución que se me ocurre es usar la función `mouseenter()` en vez del `:hover` de **CSS**, para así evitar problemas con la especifidad.